# Django SSL Operations Causing Slow API Response - How to Improve Performance?

Tags: python, django, ssl, openssl

I am a beginner at Django , I made a read request to an API endpoint in a Django application, it takes about 15 seconds to retrieve its content, which is a very long time, I profiled the Django application and got this back:

[image]

I know it is related to SSL operations, What can I do to reduce the SSL-related latency and improve the response time of my Django application when making API requests over SSL?

What I've tried:
I profiled my Django application using a profiling module and found that a significant amount of time is spent on SSL operations when making API requests to the server. I noticed that SSL handshakes and some other SSL related functions are taking a long time.

I expected the API requests to be processed much faster, like very much faster, 15 seconds is too...

Comment: 1) Is your connection to your database happening over SSL? That will show up as spending lots of time doing SSL, even if it's waiting for the database. 2) How many SSL requests are you making per page?